# Samsung 850 Pro SSD on Linux

Tags: linux, ssd, trim

I've read about the queued TRIM issue of Samsung 850 Pro SSD on Linux. They are blacklisted in the kernel for queued TRIM operations.

Are there some other, "unqueued" TRIM operations which are then being performed alternatively? I've read about the one which happens weekly or so, which basically halts disk I/O for a good amount of time; is that type of TRIM getting executed more frequently instead of the queued one?

I've also read that Windows and Mac OS don't use the queued TRIM operation, that it's a Linux only thing. So I assume that both of them (Win and MAC) aren't using that "asynchroneous"/queued TRIM operations but a synchroneous one, which also gets executed when one is blacklisted in the Linux Kernel? Am I understanding this correctly?

I'm looking for a relatively cheap 24/7 SSD to be run as the only SATA device (~240GB) on a Linux machine, mostly getting used for database applications with **only** 16GB of RAM.

I don't care about the system locking up for a sec every 30 mins or so to do SSD housekeeping tasks. Will I be on the safe side with an 850 Pro or should I go for an Intel S3500?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If queued TRIM is not supported, or not reliable, on a device then unqueued TRIM commands are used instead. This has a significant performance penalty and is the reason that the general recommendation is to keep TRIM disabled and run a full TRIM pass on a schedule at off hours (say, daily at 3AM).